# Handling Dash Character in Regular Expression for Filenames

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, typescript

I have a string which will be used to create a filename. The original string pattern may include a dash. Recently, the pattern has changed and I need to handle the regular expression to remove the dashes near the end or middle of the string but not those at the beginning of the string.

Regular Expression Pattern Rules/Requirements:

1. Replace all special characters with an underscore with some exceptions
2. Remove dashes not located at the beginning of the string
3. The dashes which need to be kept are typically between numeric values [0-9] and can appear any number of times in the string (i.e. "23-564-8 Testing - The - String" -> "23-564-8_testing_the_string")
4. The dashes which should be converted to underscores are typically between [a-zA-Z] characters (i.e. "Testing - The - String" -> "testing_the_string")

Examples of Potential Strings:

1. 23-564-8 Testing the String -> Expected Output: 23-564-8_testing_the_string
2. Testing - The String -> Expected Output: testing_the_string
3. 23-564-8 Testing - The - String -> Expected Output: 23-564-8_testing_the_string

Opinion: Personally, I'm not a fan of including dashes in filename but it is a requirement

Current Regexp Solution:

```
var str = "23-564-8 Testing the String"; 
str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/g, '_').replace(/__/g, '_');
```

Question: What is the best way to handle this case? My current solution leaves all dashes in the string.

Comment: Could you please clarify Case 2?

Comment: What is expected output for `-23-564-8 Testing - The - String` ?

Comment: Apologies, this is a typo. I've updated Case 2

Comment: -23-564-8 Testing - The - String -> 23-564-8_testing_the_string; Although, there shouldn't ever be a case where the string begins with a dash.

Comment: Then `/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+|-(?!\d)/g` might work for you. So use `str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+|-(?!\d)/g, '_').replace(/__/g, '_')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with a negative lookahead:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+|-(?!\d)/g
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+`: Match 1 or more of any character that is not hyphen or alphanumeric
- `|`: OR
- `-(?!\d)`: Match hyphen if it is NOT immediately followed by a digit

**Code:**

```js
const arr = [
'23-564-8 Testing the String',
'Testing - The String',
'-23-564-8 Testing - The - String'
]

const re = /[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+|-(?!\d)/g

var result = []

arr.forEach(el => {
  result.push( el.replace(re, '_').replace(/_{2,}/g, '_') )
})

console.log( result )
```

Comment: There is one scenario that may produce unexpected result, consider the input string: `23-564-8 Test-2`, the last dash will not be replaced with `_` character. That happens because there is a digit after the dash matched, so look-ahead requirement is satisfied.

Comment: OP can include negative lookbehind as to make it: `[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+|(?<!\d)-(?!\d)` (supported in modern Javascript)

Comment: right, I see. With another OR it should work: `[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+|-(?!\d)|-(?<!\d)`

Answer (score 0):

The following Regex pattern can be used with a replacement string `$1_` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tj7BOw/1/)):

`(\d+(?:-+\d+)+)?[\W\-_]+`

The pattern consists of two parts:

1. `(\d+(?:-+\d+)+)?` captures numbers with allowed dashes into the **Group1**
2. `[\W\-_]+` captures special characters to be replaced

The **Group1** is required to prevent *allowed* dashes from being replaced. The `$1` token in the replacement string ensures that this content of **Group1** will be kept in the result.

This Regex pattern also handles the scenario of duplicate `_` characters, so `.replace(/__/g, '_')` is no longer required. The code can be transformed to:

```js
var str = "23-564-8 Testing the String";

var res = str.replace(/(\d+(?:-+\d+)+)?[\W\-_]+/g, "$1_");

console.log(res);
```